# Shift + F10 does not work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu

I have a Dell laptop and it does not have the [right click menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key). In the preceding link it is mentioned that either <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> works as right click menu key.

The key combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> used to work for me but now it has stopped working. Neither does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>. And I can't figure out why?

Can anyone give me some pointers where I should be looking for this to work again? Can programs hijack key-combination functions? If yes then any way to find out which programs?

Answer (score 14):

If you have SnagIt installed, check it's hotkey configuration....by default, it is configured to capture Shift + F10.  Change it to something else to get Shift + F10 workiing normally again.

Comment: Thank you, it was the case for me.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8.1 has that key combination built-in. Though applications *do* have their own keyboard shortcuts, which could be hijacking that combo, another possibility is that an additional key, e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>, needs to be pressed. This "multimedia feature" can be enabled or disabled, see http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-function-key-behavior-windows-laptops or http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19267017.

If that does not resolve the issue, you may have to uninstall recently added programs, one at a time, until you find the culprit, or use System Restore to get the feature back. [If all else fails, an external mouse is ~US$5. ;-) ]

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. But mine is a Windows 10 Lenovo. Try Shift+Fn+F10. It worked for me